# What is the extra_docker_file_steps parameter in InferenceConfig() when deploying an ACI to Azure?

Tags: python, java, docker, azure-container-instances

I am deploying an ACI to Azure and need to add a Java runtime along with my normal Python environment. My inference config looks like this (deploying from Python SDK):

```
    inference_config = InferenceConfig(
        runtime="python",
        entry_script="scripts/score.py",
        conda_file="environment.yml",
        source_directory="../some dir",
        extra_docker_file_steps="",
    )
```

I was hoping to setup the java runtime and set it to the PATH and JAVA_HOME environment variables in the extra docker file steps. My question is, what format does this extra_docker_file_steps file have to be? Docker? text? I tried an empty Docker file and it failed building image.

The only documentation i can find on this is:
"extra_docker_file_steps: The path to a local file containing additional Docker steps to run when
setting up the image."

Which isn't very helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just had to deal with it today.

I used just the **extra_docker_file_steps** parameter to refer to an *extra_steps.dockerfile* file in which I defined steps to install libraries/packages to support my inference script (and not installable via Conda or PIP).

For example, to properly use *opencv* I had to install the library *ffmpeg*. So in the *dockerfile* I wrote:

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y ffmpeg
```

This way I am sure that when the image is built, *ffmpeg* is also installed.